# SparkR Error in sparkR.init(master="local") in RStudio

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I have installed the SparkR package from Spark distribution into the R library. I can call the following command and it seems to work properly: `library(SparkR)`

However, when I try to get the Spark context using the following code,

```
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
```

It fails after some time with the following message:

```
Error in sparkR.init(master = "local") :
   JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
```

I have set JAVA_HOME, and I have a working RStudio where I can access other packages like ggplot2. I don't know why it is not working, and I don't even know where to investigate the issue.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Spark/SparkR and R version, OS for starters. Did you install SparkR from repository, added binaries to `.libPaths`? Does it work outside RStudio (sparkR shell, R shell)?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and my `spark-submit.cmd` file was also not executing from the command line. Following steps worked for me

Go to your environment variables and in the system variables select variable name PATH. Along with other values add `c:/Windows/System32/` separated by a semicolon. This made my spark-submit.cmd run from command line and eventually from the Rstudio.

I have realized that we get the above issue only if all the required path values are not specified. Ensure all your path values(R, Rtools) are specified in the environment variables. For instance my Rtools path was `c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give execute permissions C:/sparkpath/bin/spark-submit.cmd. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error message. My case is a little bit different, as in I have run SparkR in RStudio successfully before. But after few days, it doesn't work anymore.

By looking at the conversion between Shivaram Venkataraman and Prakash Ponshankaarchinnusamy, I realized this may have something to do with running permission.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8603

So what I did, which eventually works, is that, I unzip the spark tar.gz to my C:/ folder again (previously it is kept in D:/ drive) AND SparkR WORKS!!!

[screenshot of working RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEdOx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After installing Hadoop followed by Spark.

`spark_path <- strsplit(system("brew info apache-spark",intern=T)[4],' ')[[1]][1] # Get your spark path
.libPaths(c(file.path(spark_path,"libexec", "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR`

Comment: is there an alternative to ``brew info`` for Windows?